# Auto-resizable JFrame Container

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize

How to make my `JFrame` auto-resizable? Size depends on existing components in the frame, but the user can add more components dynamically.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'resize' and in what form the user can 'add more'.

Comment: Lets say, that user can define options of a city. When he type "crowded" in textfield and pull enter, under first textfield a new one is created, and also frame is resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`JFrame.pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method, that according documentation:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents.

Comment: It's the best way to do this as far as I know. Although it is not at all "auto"... You would have to call this method everytime, something changes (you add/remove/resize a Component)... +1

Comment: this is right, and in fact it would be a bit weird if the window resizes every single time you add a component... so you just need to invoke pack() ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for both dynamically added components (labels added using a button - in a scroll pane), as well as a resizable GUI.

[image]